# $x^∗ ∈ C$ is an optimal solution of the problem iff $〈∇f (x),x∗ − x〉 ≤ 0$ for all $x ∈ C$.

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable convex function over a closed and convex
> set $C ⊆ \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $x∗ ∈ C$ is an optimal solution of the problem
> (P) min$\{ f (x) : x ∈ C\}$
> if and only if
> $〈∇f (x),x∗ − x〉 ≤ 0$ for all $x ∈ C$

.
The first part where I assume that $x^*$ is optimal solution and then showing the inequality I've managed to show , at the second part I've tried assuming that $x^*$ is not optimal solution and then show the inequality doesn't hold but got stuck. any hint?

Comment: Should the optimality condition read $\langle \nabla f(x^*), x^* - x \rangle \leq 0$ instead of as currently stated?

Comment: Amm.. Not sure it's from the course book. Convex analysis and optimization by amir beck. But if I read the statement right we can say it's the same because all the descent direction are in the direction of $x^*$ no?

Comment: I can't find a book with this title by Amir Beck. Did you mean the book by Bertsekas? Is it a theorem or an exercise in that book?

Comment: The answer is definitely at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4178673/if-nabla-fxt-x-x-leq-0-for-all-x-in-c-then-x-is-optimal-so?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f$ is convex, then by the Gradient Inequality $$f(\mathbf{x})\geq f(\mathbf{x}^*)+\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^*)^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^*), \quad \forall\mathbf{x}\in C.$$
Next, we assume that $\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^*)^T(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x})\leq 0$, which is the same as $\nabla f(\mathbf{x}^*)^T(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^*)\geq 0$. Using this assumption in the Gradient Inequality means that $$f(\mathbf{x})\geq f(\mathbf{x}^*), \quad \forall\mathbf{x}\in C$$
which proves the optimality of $\mathbf{x}^*$.

Comment: the statement says $\nabla f(x)^T(x^*-x)\leq0$ which is not the same as you wrote

Comment: Then the statement has a typo my friend, @VHarisop pointed out the same. You can check any resource in the world, there is no meaning to the gradient of some arbitrary $\mathbf{x}$ to prove the optimality of $\mathbf{x}^*$. Moreover, I know the book you're referring to, this is question 9.1. As Amir Beck is a professor where I study, and taught me a course from this book, I'll let him know there is a typo in the book

Comment: I guess because the typo I couldn't solve this, thank you,and I sent him a message already

Comment: I asked him and he said there is no mistake

Comment: So, Is there a typo in this statement? In Amir Beck's book, there is theorem that shows a stationarity is a necessary and sufficient condition for optimality, I think if there is typo, it will coincide with this theorem (Theorem 9.7).

Comment: @FactorY there is not typo

Comment: So for the second part, can you give me some hint? Since I got stuck in this part

Comment: The question is correct and this is not the answer to the question that is asked!

Comment: This answer is not for the question. I believe that the question is correct. But the second part is not trivial. I am working on the second part as well.